# laptop gets power off when unplugged and not charging

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, indicator

Some days ago i just turn the Lid down on my hp laptop after work and after two days i tried to power on my laptop, then i saw laptop was completely discharged. After that i just plugged in the AC adaptor to charge and then after few seconds charging indicator getting red to white(means fully charged) but when the Lap is on my battery indicator stack at 5% and in the battery details section it shows not-charging. In the battery indicator it shows a Exclamation mark inside the battery icon.

My battery is ok it's not the battery problem.

laptop is HP and OS is Ubuntu 22.04 lts.

I'm in big trouble please help me sir.

Comment: Does [this reference](https://superuser.com/questions/1589884/after-unplugging-my-laptop-and-got-shut-down-it-never-charges-to-any-and-shuts) provide any clues?

Comment: What makes you think the battery is good? I have HP laptops and have gone thru many batteries. Mine do the same thing when the battery is bad. The charge state reported by the PC
has shown up as anything from "No Battery Installed" (still worked unplugged) to "100% Charged" (died 5 seconds after unplugging). Afaik the charge led going from red to white just means the charge controller in the battery stopped charging the battery. It does not mean the battery has a full charge on it.

Comment: Battery backup was fine before this problem, how this is happened that my battery is suddenly gone..

Comment: That is the way the majority of batteries fail. Good one day bad the next day.  Note: I've had several replacement batteries fail in the warranty period. Not all retailers are good about honoring the warranty.